# Dynamically add static inheritable property to a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to add **static** inheritable properties to a class dynamically?

(My specific case is doing annotations in Typescript on properties that I want to record in the Class and accessible in subclasses but I think the question applies to javascript too)

Comment: I'm woundering if something "static" can be "dynamic". 

Static properties are shared by all instances of the class and don’t belong to any instance -> where are you going to add new properties?

It's difficult to imagine) Maybe you have some code sample?

Comment: @AndrewEvt Yes, I see the question is way too generic and needs some more specificity. I will delete this one and create another question with the specific problem.

Comment: Well finally I didn't delete as I got the solution in another question (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, from a more specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388534/how-to-store-meta-information-of-properties-in-a-class) (credit to the accepted answer there) what I was looking for is

```
class BaseClass{}
let obj = new BaseClass();
let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
Object.defineProperty(proto, "metaProperty", {
    enumerable: false, 
    writable: true      // important in order to set the metaProperty
});
proto.metaProperty = {a: 1, b: "hello"};     // Class BaseClass will have this proterty accessible in the prototype of all its instances (including derived ones)
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{}
let derived = new DerivedClass();
let theProp = Object.getPrototypeOf(derived).metaProperty;  // {a: 1, b: "hello"}
```