# How to store meta information of properties in a class

Tags: typescript, properties, metadata

I want to associate metadata to properties in classes, specifically abbreviations of property names.

With annotations: @shortName(abbreviated) you can tag each property:

```
function shortName(shortName: string){
    return function (target: Object, realName: string){
        // Where to store the relation realName <-> shortName ??
    }
}
class Record{
    @shortName("ts") typeOfStorage: string;
}
class Client extends Record{
    @shortName("df") descriptiveField: string;
}
function mapNames(obj: any){  // Return object with shortened names
    let ret = {};
    for(let prop in obj){
        //Here retrieve the short name and add to ret
    }
    return ret;
}

let client = new Client();               // supposing: { typeOfStorage: "f", descriptiveField: "blah"}
let clientShortened = mapNames(client);  // expected:  {ts: "f", df: "blah"}
```

The question is where and how do I store these relations so they are retrievable in instances of derived classes?

Initially, I was creating a global map prefixing with target.constructor.name (that gives the name of the class). But in an inherited class the constructor.name is the inherited one (so in the example `client` I'd lose track of `typeOfStorage`

(The use of this is to save space storing objects in nonSql DB -firestore- that store each property name of each object-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably store a map on the prototype of the class. When resolving properties for an object you then can acquire the prototype chain by recursively calling `Object.getPrototypeOf`, starting with the object instance. You will have to merge all the maps in the prototype chain (or just look up the property in every map individually).

```
function shortName(shortName: string)
{
    return function (target: Object, realName: string)
    {
        const t = target as { _propMap?: Map<string, string> };

        if (t._propMap == null)
        {
            // This is probably overkill, because people usually iterate
            // properties on the instances, not the prototype.
            // Setting enumerable: false hides the property.
            Object.defineProperty(t, '_propMap', {
                enumerable: false,
                writable: true,
            });

            t._propMap = new Map<string, string>();
        }

        t._propMap.set(realName, shortName);
    }
}

function getMap(obj: any)
{
    // Might want to get the chain first, then iterate in reverse
    // so child properties override parent properties
    const map = new Map<string, string>();
    while (true)
    {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        if (obj == Object.prototype)
            return map;

        if (obj._propMap)
        {
            let subMap = obj._propMap as Map<string, string>;
            subMap.forEach((v, k) => map.set(k, v));
        }
    }
}

function mapNames(obj: any)
{
    const map = getMap(obj);

    const ret: any = {};
    for (let prop in obj)
    {
        const name = map.get(prop) ?? prop;
        ret[name] = obj[prop];
    }

    return ret;
}
```